# x-forwaded-for add to http request header

Tags: web-applications, httprequest, ip-address, clientip, x-forwarded-for

My web application does not return "x-forwarded-for" header in the HTTP request. I need to this header to identify client IP as the application otherwise returns load balancer/proxy IP using getRemoteAddr().

Comment: And the problem is .... what exactly? What kind of web application are you writing?  Using what technology exactly?  Are you writing the client or the server?  Please be more specific.  Show some actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Solved this issue by asking the network team to add x-forwaded-for header in the incoming requests to the server.